# Adjusting jquery to keep image ratio in slidehow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, slideshow

I'm a huge fan of the http://unslider.com slidehow. It's great, but it distorts the image ratio to fit inside the container

Does anyone know how to adjust the standard jquery in order to achieve a result where the image keeps its ratio but still completely fills the container?

The current unslider.js looks like this:

```
(function($, f) {
//  If there's no jQuery, Unslider can't work, so kill the operation.
if(!$) return f;

var Unslider = function() {
    //  Set up our elements
    this.el = f;
    this.items = f;

    //  Dimensions
    this.sizes = [];
    this.max = [0,0];

    //  Current inded
    this.current = 0;

    //  Start/stop timer
    this.interval = f;

    //  Set some options
    this.opts = {
        speed: 500,
        delay: 3000, // f for no autoplay
        complete: f, // when a slide's finished
        keys: !f, // keyboard shortcuts - disable if it breaks things
        dots: f, // display â€¢â€¢â€¢â€¢oâ€¢ pagination
        fluid: f // is it a percentage width?,
    };

    //  Create a deep clone for methods where context changes
    var _ = this;

    this.init = function(el, opts) {
        this.el = el;
        this.ul = el.children('ul');
        this.max = [el.outerWidth(), el.outerHeight()];         
        this.items = this.ul.children('li').each(this.calculate);

        //  Check whether we're passing any options in to Unslider
        this.opts = $.extend(this.opts, opts);

        //  Set up the Unslider
        this.setup();

        return this;
    };

    //  Get the width for an element
    //  Pass a jQuery element as the context with .call(), and the index as a parameter: Unslider.calculate.call($('li:first'), 0)
    this.calculate = function(index) {
        var me = $(this),
            width = me.outerWidth(), height = me.outerHeight();

        //  Add it to the sizes list
        _.sizes[index] = [width, height];

        //  Set the max values
        if(width > _.max[0]) _.max[0] = width;
        if(height > _.max[1]) _.max[1] = height;
    };

    //  Work out what methods need calling
    this.setup = function() {
        //  Set the main element
        this.el.css({
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: _.max[0],
            height: this.items.first().outerHeight()
        });

        //  Set the relative widths
        this.ul.css({width: (this.items.length * 100) + '%', position: 'relative'});
        this.items.css('width', (100 / this.items.length) + '%');

        if(this.opts.delay !== f) {
            this.start();
            this.el.hover(this.stop, this.start);
        }

        //  Custom keyboard support
        this.opts.keys && $(document).keydown(this.keys);

        //  Dot pagination
        this.opts.dots && this.dots();

        //  Little patch for fluid-width sliders. Screw those guys.
        if(this.opts.fluid) {
            var resize = function() {
                _.el.css('width', Math.min(Math.round((_.el.outerWidth() / _.el.parent().outerWidth()) * 100), 100) + '%');
            };

            resize();
            $(window).resize(resize);
        }

        if(this.opts.arrows) {
            this.el.parent().append('<p class="arrows"><span class="prev">â†</span><span class="next">â†’</span></p>')
                .find('.arrows span').click(function() {
                    $.isFunction(_[this.className]) && _[this.className]();
                });
        };

        //  Swipe support
        if($.event.swipe) {
            this.el.on('swipeleft', _.prev).on('swiperight', _.next);
        }
    };

    //  Move Unslider to a slide index
    this.move = function(index, cb) {
        //  If it's out of bounds, go to the first slide
        if(!this.items.eq(index).length) index = 0;
        if(index < 0) index = (this.items.length - 1);

        var target = this.items.eq(index);
        var obj = {height: target.outerHeight()};
        var speed = cb ? 5 : this.opts.speed;

        if(!this.ul.is(':animated')) {          
            //  Handle those pesky dots
            _.el.find('.dot:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

            this.el.animate(obj, speed) && this.ul.animate($.extend({left: '-' + index + '00%'}, obj), speed, function(data) {
                _.current = index;
                $.isFunction(_.opts.complete) && !cb && _.opts.complete(_.el);
            });
        }
    };

    //  Autoplay functionality
    this.start = function() {
        _.interval = setInterval(function() {
            _.move(_.current + 1);
        }, _.opts.delay);
    };

    //  Stop autoplay
    this.stop = function() {
        _.interval = clearInterval(_.interval);
        return _;
    };

    //  Keypresses
    this.keys = function(e) {
        var key = e.which;
        var map = {
            //  Prev/next
            37: _.prev,
            39: _.next,

            //  Esc
            27: _.stop
        };

        if($.isFunction(map[key])) {
            map[key]();
        }
    };

    //  Arrow navigation
    this.next = function() { return _.stop().move(_.current + 1) };
    this.prev = function() { return _.stop().move(_.current - 1) };

    this.dots = function() {
        //  Create the HTML
        var html = '<ol class="dots">';
            $.each(this.items, function(index) { html += '<li class="dot' + (index < 1 ? ' active' : '') + '">' + (index + 1) + '</li>'; });
            html += '</ol>';

        //  Add it to the Unslider
        this.el.addClass('has-dots').append(html).find('.dot').click(function() {
            _.move($(this).index());
        });
    };
};

//  Create a jQuery plugin
$.fn.unslider = function(o) {
    var len = this.length;

    //  Enable multiple-slider support
    return this.each(function(index) {
        //  Cache a copy of $(this), so it 
        var me = $(this);
        var instance = (new Unslider).init(me, o);

        //  Invoke an Unslider instance
        me.data('unslider' + (len > 1 ? '-' + (index + 1) : ''), instance);
    });
};
})(window.jQuery, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set make the image container a div and set the background image like so:

```
background      : transparent url(http://img/here.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size : cover;
```

This retains the same ratio but provides optimal center-biased clipping.  To change the background image, just change the attribute:

```
$myJqImg.css( 'background-image', 'http:///new/img/here.jpg' );
```

You can create an image object to inspect the original image properties. This will preload the image, so it generally is not a waste of resources:

```
var myImg = new Image();
myImg.src = 'http://your/url/here.jpg';
myImg.onload( function (){
  width_px  = myImg.naturalWidth;
  height_px = myImg.naturalHeight;
  // use to reset size of $myJqImg within desired limits
};
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being late on this but what is going on is that you have the image width set 100% somewhere in css, just add the following to your CSS and you are set.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

or alternately the following for all such objects.

```
embed,
iframe,
object,
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```